# how can i retrieve document id of each document from Firestore in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

Here i have the code where i retrieve all the documents from Firebase, i am only able to retrieve the data present inside the document but i also want to retrieve the document Id with it, how can i do that?

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: getData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return new Text('Loading...');
              default:
                return new ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.documents
                      .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    return new CustomCard(
                      name: document['name'],
                      phone: document['phno'],
                      service: document['Category'],
                      address: document['address'],
                      pin: document['pin'],
                      payment: document['Payment'],
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
            }
          },
        ),
```

This is my getter function

```
     Stream<QuerySnapshot> getData()async*{
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection('User')
        .where("userId", isEqualTo: user.uid)
        .orderBy('upload time', descending: true)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the id, do the following:

```
 .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    return new CustomCard(
                      docId : document.documentID,
                      name: document['name'],
                      phone: document['phno'],
                      service: document['Category'],
                      address: document['address'],
                      pin: document['pin'],
                      payment: document['Payment'],
                    );
                  }).toList(),
```

`documentID` will give you each document id.

Answer (score 2):

you could as well do something like

```
snapshot.data!.docs[index].id
```

this will return the id of the document at that index